# Using ORDER BY, GROUP BY and multiple SELECT together

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

TABLE user

```
uid  | username 
----------------
1    | brandon   
2    | john   
3    | nicole
```

TABLE private_msgs

```
id   | from  | to | message      | time
-------------------------------------------
1    | 1     | 2  | hi sister    | 100
2    | 1     | 3  | hi brother   | 300
3    | 1     | 2  | hi again!    | 400
4    | 2     | 3  | lolz message | 600
```

(column time is an actual timestamp, I just made it simple for this example)

'from' is the uid of the user

'to' is the uid of the user

I want to get the newest message from all users that were sent to a specific user

The specific user in this case is

```
$logged_id = 2;
```

The results should return the row with id=3

Query I have so far

```
SELECT private_msgs.*, users.username FROM `private_msgs`, `users` 
WHERE private_msgs.to=$logged_id AND users.uid = private_msgs.from 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    from, max(time) as latest 
  FROM private_msgs 
  GROUP BY private_msgs.from
) r ON private_msgs.time = r.latest AND private_msgs.from = r.from
ORDER BY time DESC");
```

however, I am getting the error

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN ( SELECT from, max(time) as latest FROM private_msgs ' at line 3
```

Comment: This question gets asked a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in the query.  In addition to the trailing comma, `from` and `to` are reserved words, so they should be quoted:

```
SELECT pm.*, u.username
FROM `private_msgs` pm join
     `users` u
     on pm.`to` = $logged_id AND u.uid = pm.`from` INNER JOIN
     (SELECT `from`, max(time) as latest 
      FROM private_msgs 
      GROUP BY private_msgs.`from`
     ) r
    ON pm.time = r.latest AND pm.`from` = r.`from`
ORDER BY time DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you'll get newest message from all users. This is the query for your answesr

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM `user` a,` private_msgs` b 
     WHERE a.uid=b.from order by time DESC ) 
      t group by `from`
```